# error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Fila'

Tags: c, thread, struct

Estou implementando uma fila para controlar as threads criadas, em `C`. Assim enquanto a `thread` não for a primeira da fila ela aguarda para ser terminada.

exemplo:

```
//
//  Enquanto não é primeira da fila
//
while(idd   !=  PPFila.dados[PPFila.primeiro])
{

    //
    //  Aguarda
    //
    GEDI_CLOCK_Delay(50);
}
```

e nessa linha `while(idd    !=  PPFila.dados[PPFila.primeiro])`apresenta o seguinte erro: error: `error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct Fila`.

Trechos:

Struct:

```
struct  Fila
{

    int         capacidade;
    int         *dados;
    int         primeiro;
    int         ultimo;
    int         nItens;

};
```

Funcao:

```
void            funcao
            (
                char    *as_comando_buffer,
                int     an_codigo_retorno,
                char    *as_output,
                int     an_output_lenght,
                int     idd
            )
```

obs, estou utilizando delas de um outro arquivo com `extern`

```
extern  struct  Fila
PPFila,
AUTFila;
```

Alguém tem alguma dica como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Mostre a declaração de `idd`.

Comment: pronto, adicionado

Comment: Provavelmente falta-te um `#include` no ficheiro onde tens a função com o ciclo while. Suponho que nesse ficheiro não haja uma definição de `struct Fila` activa e o compilador queixa-se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` indica funções ou variáveis que estão em outros arquivos - mas não dá nenhuma dica para o compilador de qual é a assinatura de uma função, ou, no caso de structs, seu tamanho e sua estrutura real.

Para poder usar uma struct, cada arquivo .C ao ser compilado tem que "ver" a declaração da struct. Isso se faz colocando a declaração da struct num arquivo de header ( `.h` ) - e incluindo esse arquivo `.h` em todos os arquivos `.c` que você vai compilar.

Resumindo: ponha sua declaração da struct num arquivo .h separado (por exemplo, "fila.h"), e tanto no arquivo onde você cria as estruturas globais, quanto no arquivo onde ocorreu o seu erro, use a diretiva  `#include "fila.h"`.

O que eu vejo em projetos grandes  e recentes também é o costume de sempre criar um typedef com uma struct -  de forma a dispensar o uso da palavra `struct` nas declarações de estruturas desse tipo (e talvez mais algumas vantagens para o compilador e ferramentas adjacentes poderem otimizar seu código). Então , o arquivo ".h" conteria:

typedef struct  _Fila

```
{

    int         capacidade;
    int         *dados;
    int         primeiro;
    int         ultimo;
    int         nItens;

} Fila;
```

E em seguida, para declarar PPFila e AUTFila (no arquivo .c)

```
Fila PPFila, AUTFila;
```